# marginfix package interferes with title element vertical placement in memoir

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, memoir

Possibly in other classes as well. Typeset the below and everything is bunched up at the top of the page:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{marginfix}

\pretitle{\noindent\raggedright\begin{adjustwidth*}{0sp}{39bp}\fontsize{24bp}{24bp}\selectfont\MakeUppercase}
\posttitle{\end{adjustwidth*}}

\preauthor{\unskip\noindent\raggedright\normalfont\fontsize{16bp}{24bp}\selectfont\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
\postauthor{\par}

\date{}
\newcommand{\setpublisher}{\relax}
\newcommand{\publishers}[1]{\renewcommand{\setpublisher}{#1}}

\predate{\vspace*{\stretch{1}}\par\noindent\raggedright\noindent\normalfont\fontsize{12bp}{24bp}\MakeUppercase\setpublisher}
\postdate{\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage}

\begin{document}
\title{Title goes here}
\publishers{Publishing information here}
\author{Author Name}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

comment out the `marginfix` package and the publishers data properly goes to the bottom.

Suggestions?

Comment: Are you using the latest version (2013/09/08 v1.1)?  I can't reproduce this.

Comment: Given that I'm using: [William-Adamss-iMac-2:~] williamadams% kpsewhich marginfix.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/marginfix/marginfix.sty
one would think I would be, but that is dated 10/18/11 and says 2010/08/28 v0.9.1 Fix Margin Paragraphs, obviously not. I'll try up-dating it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the problem is caused by outdated packages.